# Changing image layout in CSS mobile media query

Tags: css, image, layout, media, responsive

I have three images side by side in my web page and in the responsive CSS media query for mobile, I want the third image to be centered on the next line with the first two above it, one floating left, one floating right. I can't do it! How do I write this CSS?

Comment: pls share you html and css file.

Comment: can you share some of your css & html? Also are you using any frameworks such as Bootstrap or Foundation?

Comment: you can show your html and css file using pinterest or jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You should share you code, but I'll try to help you even so.

```
<div class="main">
<div class="image-left"><img src=""></div>
<div class="image-right"><img src=""></div>
<div class="image-center"><img src=""></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.main {
position: relative;
max-width: 100%;
}
.image-left {
  float: left;
}
.image-center {
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-left: 10% ;
  position: absolute;
}
```

You need to adjust .image-center { margin-top and margin-left according to your layout.

If you need space between image-left and image-right, you add another class;

```
.image-right {
margin-left: 10px;
}
```